# How to pass props from one component to an another component in WeChat Mini-Program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wechat, wechat-auth

I am  new to WeChat Mini program development. I came from React Technology there we were passing custom attributes ( props ) from one component to an another. I am trying to pass props from one component to another component but here I am failed. Please help me how to send props in WeChat Mini-Program .

Thanks

**First Component Code**

```
    <!--index.wxml-->
<view class="container">
    <headerComponent prop-a="{{dataFieldA}}" prop-b="{{dataFieldB}}" />
</view>
```

**Second Component Code**

```
    <!--components/header.wxml-->
<text>Header Component</text>
<text>{{prop-a}}</text>
```

I am trying but `prop-a` data is not showing it give me result `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Try declare a variable use `camelCase`(propA) not `camel-case`(prop-a).

And don't forget declare props in `component.properties` like below,

```
Component({
  properties: {
    propA: {
      type: String
    }
  }
```

```
<text>Header Component</text>
<text>{{propA}}</text>
```

And it should work;